# How to display lightning modal pop-up (invoked by visualforce) above the record detail page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, modal

Hi I am trying to replace the standard new button in one of the related list of the Quote object.
I am succesfully doing it except that when the custom button is clicked, the modal is displayed on a separate page instead on the Quote record detail page as a pop-up. I'm quite stucked on this one, can someone help me with this?

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" recordSetVar="quotes" tabStyle="quote" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <div id="lightning" />
            <script>
            $Lightning.use("c:myCustomApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:myCustomComp",
                                           { label : "object Creation" },
                                           "lightning",
                                           function(cmp) {
                                               //

                                           });
            });
            </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

myCustomApp:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:myCustomComp"/> 
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

myCustomComp

```
<aura:component controller="MYController" access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
  
    <div aura:id="exampleModal" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open hideDiv" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_small" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                //my FORM       
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="dialog"></div> 
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

Comment: You're not stuck--it's literally impossible to do what you ask using Lightning Out.

Comment: Thank you so much @sfdcfox for replying! Do you have an idea/suggestion to achieve this? I'm trying to mimic the standard New button on the related list so it has to be a visualforce but the look and feel should be lightning

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to link to your component directly from the button. Just make it [URL addressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation), and then use the URL list button type, such as:

```
/lightning/cmp/c__myCustomComp?c__id={!Account.Id}
```

You can still have it look like a modal, but the page behind will be navigated to a new temporary tab. This is, I believe, the only way to stay in the same window and use your component.